# Compare list String values with array list

Tags: android, listview

I have listview with text in check box in every row. I am saving the  selected values in a list on button click and then close the app when i open the app i am checking if all the values of list are there in the listview or not. If yes, then I want to set the checkboxes of those values as selected. How to to do this? Can any one help me?

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    String str, str1;
    SharedPreferences pref;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        displayListView();

        checkButtonClick();


    }

    private void displayListView()
    {





        //Array list of countries
        ArrayList<States> stateList = new ArrayList<States>();

        States _states = new States("AP","Andhra Pradesh",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("DL","Delhi",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("GA","Goa",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("JK","Jammu & Kashmir",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("KA","Karnataka",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("KL","Kerala",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("RJ","Rajasthan",false);
        stateList.add(_states);
        _states = new States("WB","West Bengal",false);
        stateList.add(_states);






        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.state_info, stateList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }

    private void checkButtonClick()
    {

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                ArrayList<States> stateList = dataAdapter.stateList;



                for(int i=0;i<stateList.size();i++)
                {

                    States state = stateList.get(i);

                    if(state.isSelected())

                    {



                        responseText.append("\n" + state.getName());


                        sb.append(state.getName());

                        sb.append(",");
                        if (sb.length() > 0 ) {
                             str = sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1);
                        }



                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                System.out.println(str);

                pref.edit().putString("key", str).apply();


            }
        });
    }


}
```

```css
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<States> {

    public ArrayList<States> stateList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<States> stateList)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.stateList = new ArrayList<States>();
        this.stateList.addAll(stateList);
         this.getSelectedList();
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null)
        {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.state_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    States _state = (States) cb.getTag();

                 /*   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

                    _state.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });



        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        States state = stateList.get(position);



        holder.code.setText(" (" + state.getCode() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(state.getName());
        holder.name.setChecked(state.isSelected());

        holder.name.setTag(state);

        return convertView;
    }

     private void getSelectedList(){

         pref = get Context().getSharedPreferences("MYPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String text = pref.getString("key","");
List<String> selectedList = Arrays.asList(text.split(","));
for(States state: this.stateList){
    if(selectedList.contains(state.getName())){
       state.setSelected(true);
    }


 }

      }

}
```

```html
public class States  {

    String code = null;
    String name = null;
    boolean selected = false;

    public States(String code, String name, boolean selected) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem. Let's make a small change in your adapter.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<States> {

    public ArrayList<States> stateList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<States> stateList)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.stateList = new ArrayList<States>();
        this.stateList.addAll(stateList);
        this.getSelectedList();

    }

    private void getSelectedList()
    {

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = pref.getString("key","");
        List<String> selectedList = Arrays.asList(text.split(","));

        for (State state: this.stateList) {
            if (selectedList.contains(state.getName())) {
                state.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code but I'm getting NullPointerException in the line `pref.edit().putString("key", str).apply();` in MainActivity @anhtuannd

Comment: I've also updated the whole code.

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved it. And thanks so much, your code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < stateList.size(); i++) {
    States state = stateList.get(i);
    if (list.contains(state.getName()))
       state.setSelected(true);
}
```

Delete these lines

```
if (sb.length() > 0 ) {
    str = sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1);
}
```

in `checkButtonClick`.

```
str = sb.toString();
pref.edit().putString("key", str).apply();
```